# How do I add an existing query as a new column? PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I just want to add a query to an existing table as a new column. This is what I tried but its wrong but it shows the general idea.

```
alter table table_name1
add column datetime timestamp as
    select
        concat(date,' ',case when military_hour <10 then concat('0',military_hour) else military_hour::varchar end,':00:00')::timestamp
    from table_name1
```

Comment: Can you please try to elaborate what you are trying to achieve? And add any error-messages as well.

Comment: I have a select query. I want to add it into an existing table, as a new column. I want the column to be filled by my query upon being added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a new column with a calculated value based on existing columns in PostgreSQL, you can use the ALTER TABLE statement along with the ADD COLUMN clause. However, you cannot directly use a SELECT statement within the ADD COLUMN clause.

ALTER TABLE table_name1 ADD COLUMN new_column_name timestamp;

UPDATE table_name1
SET new_column_name = CONCAT(date, ' ', CASE WHEN military_hour < 10 THEN CONCAT('0', military_hour) ELSE military_hour::varchar END, ':00:00')::timestamp;

** After executing these SQL statements, the new_column_name will be added to the table_name1 table, and the values will be calculated based on the concatenation and conversion logic you provided.